# Does Google routinely form contracts by accessing web sites with their crawler?

Tags: internet, terms-of-service, google, adhesion-contracts

Many web sites contain terms of service, where the web site puts a link to "Terms" or similar, and anyone who accesses the web site forms a contract with the web site operator under those offered terms.

Google operates a web crawler that accesses almost all web sites, including, generally, the pages that define the contract terms for accessing the web site.

Is Google Inc. forming contracts with huge numbers of web sites by accessing them while on notice of their terms of service? If not, why not?

Comment: robots.txt was created for a reason...

Comment: The web sites usually want Google to access them, not to exclude it. But they might also want to bind Google to arbitration and get an indemnity from them in case something bad happens to someone else because of Google accessing the site.

Comment: Robots.txt has no legal weight.  I am not sure what it matters what websites want, either a machine can accept a browser wrap licence or they can not.  If they can not, surely anyone can avoid accepting such a contract with a browser extension.